Cloud SQL MySQL Connection Refused: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] – How to Resolve?
I'm trying to connect my application to a Google Cloud SQL instance running MySQL, but I'm encountering a "Connection refused" error. Below are the details of the error and the steps I’ve taken so far to troubleshoot it
Error Message
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select *  
from information_schema.tables where table_schema = vibyz and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Detailed Log:
2024-06-18 13:11:21.993 WET
failed to refresh the ephemeral certificate for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: ensure that the account has access to "viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during generateEphemeral for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: googleapi: Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.connect on resource instances/viby-z-db., forbidden
2024-06-18 13:11:21.994 WET
Cloud SQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: ensure that the account has access to "viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during generateEphemeral for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: googleapi: Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.connect on resource instances/viby-z-db., forbidden
2024-06-18 13:11:22.197 WET
failed to refresh the ephemeral certificate for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: ensure that the account has access to "viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during generateEphemeral for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: googleapi: Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.connect on resource instances/viby-z-db., forbidden
2024-06-18 13:11:22.198 WET
Cloud SQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: ensure that the account has access to "viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during generateEphemeral for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: googleapi: Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.connect on resource instances/viby-z-db., forbidden
2024-06-18 13:11:22.199 WET
Cloud SQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: ensure that the account has access to "viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during generateEphemeral for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: googleapi: Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.connect on resource instances/viby-z-db., forbidden
2024-06-18 13:11:22.199 WET
Cloud SQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: ensure that the account has access to "viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during generateEphemeral for viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db: googleapi: Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.connect on resource instances/viby-z-db., forbidden
2024-06-18 13:11:22.235 WET
In Connection.php line 795:


2024-06-18 12:39:49.623 WET
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
(Connection: mysql, SQL: select *  
from information_schema.tables where table_schema = vibyz and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
2024-06-18 12:39:50.451 WET
Container called exit(1).
2024-06-18 12:39:50.520 WET
Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "placeholder-1" on port 80. The instance was not started.


Steps I’ve Taken:

Verified Database Credentials:

Ensured the database host, port, username, and password are correctly set in the application configuration.


Checked Database Host and Port:

Confirmed the database host is the correct IP address or connection name for the Cloud SQL instance.

Using the default MySQL port (3306).



Ensured Cloud SQL Instance is Running:

Verified the Cloud SQL instance viby-z-db is running in the Google Cloud Console.


Validated Firewall and Network Settings:

Checked that the IP address of my application is included in the authorized networks for the Cloud SQL instance.


Attempted Connection Using Cloud SQL Proxy:

Tried using the Cloud SQL Proxy to connect securely, but still faced connection issues.


Checked SSL/TLS Configuration:

Verified that SSL/TLS is properly configured if required for the connection.


Reviewed Application Logs and Configuration:
      No additional clues found in the logs that explain the connection refusal.


Reviewed IAM Permissions:

Ensured the service account used by the application has the Cloud SQL Client role.

The service account appears to lack permissions to refresh the ephemeral certificate as indicated by the 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED error.




Environment Details:

Cloud SQL Instance: viby-z-425216:europe-west1:viby-z-db

MySQL Version: 8.0

Application: PHP with PDO MySQL

Google Cloud Environment: Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)



Have you enabled the Cloud SQL Admin API? If the Cloud SQL instance is in a different project then your application you will need to enabled the Cloud SQL Admin API in both projects.

If you are connecting to a Cloud SQL instance which lives in a different project then you will need to add the service account as an IAM principle in the project where the Cloud SQL instance lives and give it the Cloud SQL Client role in that project, not the one where the application lives.
